# How to fix 'qr_code' is not a registered tag library. in Django and HTML

Tags: python, django, installation, django-templates, qr-code

How to fix 'qr_code' is not a registered tag library. I use Django version 4.1.4.

setting.py

```bash
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'qrcode',
]
```

In setting.py, if I use qr_code instead of qrcode, this error will occur ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qr_code'.

It will display the error 'qr_code' is not a registered tag library.

```bash
{% load qr_code %}
{% qr_from_text request.build_absolute_uri size="T" image_format="png" error_correction="T" %}
```

In HTML, how should I edit?

Command I used to install

```bash
django-qr-code 3.1.1 
pip install django-qr-code
```

And I tried installing it with conda after trying it in pip and it didn't work.

```bash
conda install -c auto django-qrcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed a different library. Indeed, you installed [**`django-qrcode`** <sup>[pypi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/django-qrcode/), not [**`django-qr-code`** <sup>[pypi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/django-qr-code/).

The two are however very similar, you only need to work with:

```
{% load qr_tags %}

{% qr_from_text request.build_absolute_uri size="T" image_format="png" error_correction="T" %}
```

Comment: Thank, I tried it but it's an error 'qr_tags' is not a registered tag library.
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'qrcode'
]